# How to get name of user who has (Excel) file open on server, using Access VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

There are multiple Excel files on a server (or network shared storage location).

I have an Access document that needs access to these Excel files to execute a certain function.

When one of these files is open I can not execute my VBA function.

I check if someone is using the file. This is in the code below.

Is it is possible to also find out who is using a file. I would notify them to close the file(s).

Some of the things I tried (these are not all, but I can’t find a few methods anymore that I tried too):
https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/return-user-name-who-has-file-open.31447/
https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/87346-vba-code-to-determine-who-has-file-open

In the last one they get the owner of the file and that is not the same as the one that is using the file at that moment. I tried it, but even then I sometimes get a username, but the username of the one that created the file and sometimes I get a SID (Security Identifier?).

Code to find out if the file is in use. This does not include anything to see who is using the file.

```vb
Sub TestFileOpened()
    Dim filesArray As Variant
    filesArray = Array("Map1.xlsx", "Map2.xlsx")
    Dim fileLocation As String
    fileLocation = "\\DESKTOP-NETWORK\SharedFolder\NetwerkTest\"
    Dim message As String
    
    For Each file In filesArray
        If IsFileOpen(fileLocation & file) Then
            message = message & vbNewLine & "File '" & file & "' is open!"
        'Else
        '    message = message & vbNewLine & "File '" & file & "' is closed!"
        End If
    Next file
    
    MsgBox message
    
End Sub
```

Function to check if the file is in use:

```vb
Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer
    
    On Error Resume Next
    filenum = FreeFile()
    
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum
    errnum = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Select Case errnum
        Case 0
            IsFileOpen = False
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select
End Function
```

Access and Excel are able to do exactly that when you try to manually open the file. Superuser post: https://superuser.com/questions/845084/how-to-get-excel-to-show-username-of-person-that-has-file-open

Comment: You can add some code to the files to be checked, which create logs that you can then reference in your code.  Here is an example.  https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/find-out-who-has-excel-file-locked-for-editing-with-vba/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i am not good in writing descent macro's, so modify code to suit your own needs!

This one should give the name of the user who has currently opened an Excel-sheet:

```
Sub InUse(filename As String)
    Dim f
    Dim i
    Dim x
    Dim inUseBy
    Dim tempfile
    tempfile = Environ("TEMP") + "\tempfile" + CStr(Int(Rnd * 1000))
    
    f = FreeFile
    i = InStrRev(filename, "\")
    If (i > 0) Then
        filename = Mid(filename, 1, i) + "~$" + Mid(filename, 1 + i)
    Else
        filename = "~$" + filename
    End If
    
    Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.CopyFile filename, tempfile
    
    Open tempfile For Binary Access Read As #f
    Input #f, x
    Close (f)
    inUseBy = Mid(x, 2, Asc(x))
    fso.Deletefile tempfile
    Set fso = Nothing

    MsgBox "InUse by: " + inUseBy, vbOKOnly, "InUse"
    
End Sub
```

Example use:

```
InUse("T:\Book1.xlsx")
```

Things to note:

0. This should be used when opening of a sheet fails (because of bein in-use)
1. I did not find any documentation about this being the 'valid' way to do this.
2. I do not know if this also works with shared excel sheets

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I don't know why you think you are bad at writing macro's, because the code you provided works perfectly.
Some tips: Try to add some comments or at least explain what you do in your code, now I had to do some research and still don't understand everything (a lot). F.e. the Mid function, why does it have to be "Mid(x, 2, Asc(x))" ? Where and how did you find that? Also try not to use short variables like "x, y, i" but give them a decent name.
The above will help everyone in reading and understanding the code.

Comment: Why `Mid(x, 2, Asc(x))` Because i need something on the second position of the `x` i did read.   The biggest problem  with this macro is not the lack of my comments, but the lack of documentation about the (internal) format of a tempfile created by Excel.

Comment: The code you provided works great, but from time to time I get an error on line `inUseBy = Mid(x, 2, Asc(x))` because `x` is empty. Do you have any idea what the cause could be? If `tempfile` was the problem an error should have been thrown much earlier I think.
For some reason I'm not able to see the files with `~$` on the server but locally I can. Maybe that's the problem? But then again, why does it work most of the time, but only a few times it doesn't (?)...

Comment: The requires a lot of debugging....  Another approach to this problem might be to get the Owner of the temporarily created file. This file is normally created Hidden, so it might not be visible under Explorer.   But, because there is no publicly available documentation about this, i can/will not put much time in this (sorry).

Answer (score 2):

This is ingenious - but very slightly risky - but only because the subroutine modifies its input parameter!  I've tarted it up a bit here, and also added a check for if the file is not in use by anyone!  I've also enhanced it to make it more readable.  This also fixes a bug affecting 13-character long login names (13 = x0d = vbCr!).

```vb
Function InUseBy(FileName As String) As String
'
' This fixes:
' a. 13 character long usernames
' b. does not modify the supplied FileName value
'
' Note: not tested on Excel-sharable workbooks
'
    Dim WorkFile As String
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim iptr As Integer
    Dim buffer As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim NameLength As Integer
    Dim rezult As Variant
'
' Invent a temporary workfile name
'
    WorkFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\Workfile" & CStr(Int(Rnd * 1000))
'
' Derive the Excel temporary file that will exist if it's open for update
'
    iptr = InStrRev(FileName, "\")
    If iptr > 0 Then
        TempFile = Mid(FileName, 1, iptr) & "~$" & Mid(FileName, 1 + iptr)
    Else
        TempFile = "~$" & FileName
    End If
'
' If the temporary file does not exist then the supplied file is either not open, or it's open read-only
'
    If Dir(TempFile, vbHidden + vbSystem) = "" Then  
'
' - it's not open, or open read-only
'
       InUseBy = "No-one, or open read-only"
'
' Else copy the contents of the temporary file to the workfile
'
    Else
       Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       fso.CopyFile TempFile, WorkFile
'
' - try to open the workfile
'
       On Error Resume Next
       Set ts = fso.GetFile(WorkFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
       rezult = Err.Number
       On Error GoTo 0
'
' --  if successful then extract the user's username
'     (the INPUT approach fails if username is length 13, because it sees x0D as a carriage-return character!)
'     (record format is Nusername... where N is the length of username (max 255))
'
       If rezult = 0 Then
          buffer = ts.readall
          ts.Close
          Set ts = Nothing
'
          NameLength = Asc(buffer)
          InUseBy = Mid(buffer, 2, NameLength)
'
' -- else return an error
'
       Else
          InUseBy = "Error " & rezult & " reading temporary file"
       End If
'
' - delete the workfile
'
       fso.Deletefile WorkFile
       Set fso = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I assume your first sentence "This is ingenious - but very slightly risky - but only because the subroutine modifies its input parameter!" actually refers to the earlier answer by @Luuk (i.e. and not this answer)? If so can I check that the risk you are referring to is that the calling code (i.e. of @Luuk's Sub) may not be expecting the variable it uses to pass the String for the `filename` will be modified?

Comment: Also you do not declare `ts` which I guess should be `As Object` as you are using late binding?

Comment: You're right - I was looking to make a generic routine, based on the method discussed - so I had to fix that first.  Apologies if I got the thread a bit cross-threaded!  The first time I tried it, it failed as the user editing the file has a 13-character long username!  Another thing to bear in mind is that, with this approach, if the user who'd opened the file for update access crashes out, the ~$ ownership file is still there, which might even be yourself!
 The program calling this routine must take that possibility into account.